# await Promise causes following awaits to be outside ngZone

Tags: angular

Angular 6, cli 6

I've been having some problems recently with a change detection not happening in a subscribe - if I perform a `detectChanges()` then things work peachy.

This has led me to discover that an http call is running outside the zone, which is disturbing.

After some hunting , I've narrowed it down to this code ..

I have a base http service that uses the httpClient to make requests, and this is extended for each "api".

```
/* base service */
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
...
constructor(
        protected http: HttpClient
...
/* construct request, and call */
console.log('xxxx', url, NgZone.isInAngularZone());
return this.http.request(request)
```

now in the component I have

const [yy, xx] = await Promise.all([
  this._labelApi.find().toPromise(),
  this._workspaceApi.find().toPromise()
]);

const z = await this._labelApi.find().toPromise();

where `_labelApi` and `_workspaceApi` are classes that have extended the base service

ignoring the code, the really interesting thing is the console messages

```
xxxx /api/Labels true
xxxx /api/Workspaces true
xxxx /api/Labels false
```

so when second identical call to `/api/Labels` is performed, this time it is not in the zone ...

if I change the code to be

```
    const a = await this._labelApi.find().toPromise();
    const z = await this._labelApi.find().toPromise();
    const b = await this._workspaceApi.find().toPromise();
```

then the console result is

```
xxxx /api/Labels true
xxxx /api/Labels false
xxxx /api/Workspaces false
```

so it looks to me as if the first http call then throws any other http out of the zone. Which is very, very odd.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here ?

Thanks

**Update #1**
I'm pretty sure that this is to do with `toPromise()`. If I change the code to read

```
    this._labelApi.find().subscribe();
    this._labelApi.find().subscribe();
    this._workspaceApi.find().subscribe();
```

then the console reads

```
    xxxx /api/Labels true
    xxxx /api/Labels true
    xxxx /api/Workspaces true
```

but, of course, it makes awaiting for a http request before starting another a little more tricky

**Update #2**
If I change the target in `tsconfig` from `esnext` to `es5` then the code works as I expected.

So, if I were to hazard a guess, something is not right with the typescript -> exnext transpiler